# Read CSV row 1 columns and save them to variables

Tags: powershell, csv

I would like to read data from csv or another txt files. Data should been read only from row 1 and few columns on row 1 and save them to variables and after saving delete the row. Now I have done it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path | ForEach-Object -Process {
$YourContent = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
$YourVariable = $YourContent | Select-Object -First 1
$YourContent | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
```

My problem is that my variable prints out like this :

```
Elvis;867.5390;elvis@geocities.com
```

So I would like to save each variable to its own column. Example what csv could look:

```
Elvis | 867.5309     | Elvis@Geocities.com
Sammy | 555.1234     | SamSosa@Hotmail.com
```

Comment: so you want to -- [1] read in the 1st line of each file -- [2] convert that line into an object using only SOME of the properties ///// is that correct? if so, try using `Get-Contnet -TotalCount 1` to get the 1st line, then use `ConvertFrom-CSV` to convert that line into an object.

Comment: What are you doing with `$YourVariable`? You mention CSV, your variable is already very close to being one... just replace `;` with `,` like this `$YourVariable = ($YourContent | Select-Object -First 1) -replace (';',',')`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content`:

```
Import-Csv file.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header A, B, C
```

Comment: How does it solve the req. to read first line, process and save without it? You'd have to `|ConvertTo-Csv|Select-Object -Skip 2|Set-Content ...` and the original format will be overwritten by double qouted versions.

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do what i think you want.

1. the 1st 8 lines make a file to work with. [*grin*]
2. line 10 reads in that file
3. lines 11-13 convert the 1st line into an object & remove the unwanted property
4. lines 14-15 grab all BUT the 1st line & send it to overwrite the source file
5. the remaining lines show what was done [*grin*]

Code:

```
$FileName = "$env:TEMP\Pimeydentimo.txt"

# create a file to work with
@'
Alfa;123.456;Some unwanted info;Alfa@example.com
Bravo;234.567;More info that can be dropped;Bravo@example.com
Charlie;345.678;This is also ignoreable;Charlie@example.com
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $FileName

$InStuff = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FileName
$TempObject = $InStuff[0] |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Name', 'Number', 'DropThisOne', 'Email' |
    Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty DropThisOne
$InStuff[1..$InStuff.GetUpperBound(0)] |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $FileName    

$InStuff
'=' * 30
$TempObject
'=' * 30
Get-Content -LiteralPath $FileName
```

output ...

```
Alfa;123.456;Some unwanted info;Alfa@example.com
Bravo;234.567;More info that can be dropped;Bravo@example.com
Charlie;345.678;This is also ignoreable;Charlie@example.com
==============================

Name Number  Email           
---- ------  -----           
Alfa 123.456 Alfa@example.com
==============================
Bravo;234.567;More info that can be dropped;Bravo@example.com
Charlie;345.678;This is also ignoreable;Charlie@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

I try to clarify a bit more what i was trying to do. Answers might do it already, but I'm not yet that good in Powershell and learning still a alot.

If I have csv or any other txt file, i would want to read the first row of the file.  The row contains more than one piece of information.  I want also save each piece of information to Variables. After saving information to variables, I would like to delete the row.

Example:

Car    Model      Year

Ford   Fiesta      2015

Audi   A6           2018

In this example, i would like to save Ford, Fiesta and 2015 to variables (row 1)($Card, $Model, $Year) and after it delete the row.  The 2nd row should not be deleted, because it is used later on